# Why is $(qy + r, y) = (r,y)$ if $R$ is a Ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ is a Ring and $x,y,q,r \in R$ with $x = qy + r$. 
How i can show that $(x,y) = (r,y)$?

Many thanks for some hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: showing that $(x,y) \subseteq (r,y)$ and $(r,y) \subseteq (x,y)$ will give you $(x,y)=(r,y)$.